# Not able to access value of formArray in Angular

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, formarray

I am not able to access formarray value on Using Reactive form in my Angular Project

my response is coming like this  :

{appearsOnce: "InitialValue"
formArray: Array[0]}

**after typing value in the form Array and submitting form still I am getting array as 0**

I am sharing my code which exists in slack-blitz link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x6mwfj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

CODE :

TS :

```
 inputArray: any = [];
myForm: FormGroup;
 constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
    ngOnInit(): void {
        let newForm = this.fb.group({
            appearsOnce: ['InitialValue', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(25)]],
            formArray: this.fb.array([])
        });

        const arrayControl = <FormArray>newForm.controls['formArray'];
        this.inputArray.forEach(item => {
            let newGroup = this.fb.group({
                propertyOne: [''],
                propertyTwo: ['']
            });
            arrayControl.push(newGroup);
        });

        this.myForm = newForm;
    }
    addInput(): void {

        const arrayControl = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['formArray'];
        let newGroup = this.fb.group({

           propertyOne: ['InitialValue'],
                propertyTwo: ['InitialValue']

        });
        arrayControl.push(newGroup);
    }
    delInput(index: number): void {
        const arrayControl = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['formArray'];
        arrayControl.removeAt(index);
    }
    onSubmit(): void {
        console.log(this.myForm.value);

    }
```

html :

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
    <label>Appears Once:</label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="appearsOnce" />






    <div formArrayName="formArray">
        <div *ngFor="let control of myForm.controls['formArray'].controls; let i = index">
            <button type="button" (click)="delInput(i)">Delete</button>
            <!-- <my-form-sub-component [myForm]="myForm.controls.formArray.controls[i]"></my-form-sub-component> -->
            <div [formGroup]="newGroup">
    <label>Property One: </label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="propertyOne"/>

    <label >Property Two: </label>
    <input type="number" formControlName="propertyTwo"/>
</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" (click)="addInput()">Add + </button>
    <button type="submit" class='btn' [disabled]="!myForm.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FormArray are index based.So you have to pass index to formGroupName directive like this

**component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
    <label>Appears Once:</label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="appearsOnce" />
    <div formArrayName="formArray">
        <div *ngFor="let control of myForm.get('formArray').controls; let i = index">
            <button type="button" (click)="delInput(i)">Delete</button>
            <div [formGroupName]="i">
                <label>Property One: </label>
                <input type="text" formControlName="propertyOne"/>

                <label >Property Two: </label>
                <input type="number" formControlName="propertyTwo"/>
</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" (click)="addInput()">Add + </button>
        <button type="submit" class='btn' [disabled]="!myForm.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

[Forked Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9h6jws)